# animation not starting!! (android)

Tags: android, animation, listener

can anyone tell me why this animation isn't starting? i've tried putting code in the onAnimationStart listener and it is never called! there are no errors, it just never happens.. i've been staring at this for hours!!!

```
Animation bRegisterAnimation = fadeView(1,0,0);
bRegisterAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {}
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        bRegister.clearAnimation();
        bRegister.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
bRegister.setAnimation(bRegisterAnimation);
```

and here is the fadeView function:

```
public Animation fadeView(float startA, float endA, int delay) {
    Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(startA,endA);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setStartOffset(delay);
    return animation;
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess bRegister is your view over which you want your animation to work. IF this is so, you have correctly set the animation with this view using bRegister.setAnimation(bRegisterAnimation);

but you haven't started the animation using startAnimation(). Try it once

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `bRegister.startAnimation(bRegisterAnimation)`. Also, you don't need to call `setAnimation()`. If you're trying to make a simple fade animation, you might try using this instead:

```
bRegister.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                    getBaseContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
```

Comment: thanks for reminding me that Android R class has built in animations ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience when trying to implement animations on my Android device, which was one that I borrowed from my sister. I tried getting animation to work on it for a whole day until I finally gave up. Days later was when I realized...... all animations had been turned off in the settings -***_***- lol so to avoid wasting your time like me it might be wise to check your settings first.

Comment: I can't even explain how grateful I am that you posted this, almost lost my mind. Thank youuuuuuu!!!!